# Firebase onCreate method not triggering

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have a onCreate function which is not triggering. Here's the code -

```
exports.listen = functions.database.ref('/GSTTiasQ3gWtYOEWbTwpwd8dL4G2/{id}').onCreate(async (change, context) => {
    console.log(change);
    return;
});
```

And here is my database hierarchy

[image: Firebase]

I am checking the logs in firebase emulator.

Comment: Did you deploy the function?

Comment: No. I am using Firebase emulator for development. I haven't deployed anything yet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65503336/run-firebase-functions-emulator-on-database-without-database-emulator-towards-p Tl;dr - Not possible. Deploy to use google database.

Comment: well if you are using firebase emulator make sure u test on the firebase realtime database on the emulator and make sure u deploy your function to the firebase emulator

Answer (score 0):

You talk about an onWrite function but that's not the same as an onCreate function, which only triggers on document creation

[Firebase function documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)